# Using Ribbon control with PRISM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I want to create a composite wpf application with ribbon control using Prism,
and I have some thoughts about commanding:

The ribbon tab is in different view, so i guess it will have specific view model. but the command should be in another view model, because when I click on button in the ribbon, I want to do some action in the view below, so how can I bind it? should I use Event Aggregator to communicate between the view models? maybe Composite command? any other approch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a different Views/ViewsModels - EventAggregator is a way to go. You use command on a View with ribbon that executes Method on RibbonViewModel which will Publish that event. Other views subscribe to that event.

If you use Ribbon as a menu - then maybe you should use PRISM's Navigation to open other views (in different region)

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical scenario for composite commands